# Check if there are any unique tokens left of a certain character length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.3

I have a Post model with the attribute `token`.

I'm using `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(length_of_token)` to create a token.

The token doesn't need to be unguessable, but must be unique.

I'm starting with tokens 1 character long, and when they are all used up (all 64 combinations), I should move on to have tokens that are 2 characters long.

How should I check if there are any token variations left for tokens that are 3 characters long?

Comment: The method argument specifies the number of _bytes_. Therefore, `urlsafe_base64(1)` generates 256 values, `urlsafe_base64(2)` generates 65,536 values and so on (256^n). Besides, assuming that 65,535 tokens of "length" 2 have been created (only one is left), how do you generate that last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like :

```
64**n - Post.count(:token).where('char_length(token) = ?', n)
```

The first part gives the number of combinations possible and the second the number of records with a token length of n.

But don't forget that your random generator won't necessarily generate the remaining possible combinations. There will be exponentially more and more collisions over the time, therefore I'd strongly discourage this kind of implementation.

Note: The `char_length` statement is MySQL specific, so depending on your RDBMS, you'll have to adapt this part.

Comment: Note that `64 ^ n` is not equivalent to `64 ** n`

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I changed it